# Bash test value of last function equal to zero

Tags: bash

Using blueutil to try to connect or disconnect my headphones, when you test using the --is-connected it returns either a 0 or 1. I want to use that to either connect or disconnect the headphones, but I keep getting a "0: command not found" error.

```
blueutil --is-connected ac-90-85-3e-0d-04
if $? -eq 0
  then
    blueutil --connect ac-90-85-3e-0d-04
  else
    blueutil --disconnect ac-90-85-3e-0d-04
fi
```

Comment: Try to set like this EXIT_STATUS=$? and then if $EXIT_STATUS -eq 0

Comment: @rootkonda, that has the same problem the OP's original code does -- it's trying to run `$EXIT_STATUS` as a command, which it isn't (even when passed `-eq` as its first argument and `0` as its second).

Comment: Related: [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: But thats how we refer shell variables right ? $variable_name. Atleast this should work if $EXIT_STATUS = 0

Comment: @rootkonda This has nothing to do with the variable being used, but the fact that `$? -eq 0` isn't a valid *command*. `?` is a perfectly valid *parameter* name (a variable being a particular kind of parameter in `bash`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell doesn't do comparisons by itself; that's the job of the `test` command:

```
if test $? -eq 0
```

though all `if` does is look at the exit status of its condition list; you can call `blueutil` directly from that list.

```
if blueutil --is-connected ac-90-85-3e-0d-04
  then
    blueutil --connect ac-90-85-3e-0d-04
  else
    blueutil --disconnect ac-90-85-3e-0d-04
fi
```